# This is button has been duplicate in my php coding

Tags: php, button, duplicates, switch-statement

There is two buttons but I don't know why did my button duplicate.

I tried using if and still did the same thing to the button. 
I tried using a include function but still didn't go any where.
Here is my code:[image]

```
<?php include"php-MAIN-Info.php"; 
include"php-MAIN-SignUp+DataBase.php"; $result1 =
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE user_one =
'".$User_ID."' OR user_two = '".$User_ID."'");

 1. List item

if ($result1) {     while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $day = $_SESSION['Info_User_ID'];       $longShift = true;

        switch (true) {

            case ($day == $row1['user_one']):
                echo " ";
                break;

            case ($day == $row1['user_two']):
                echo " ";
                break;

            case ($day == 'Friday' && !$longShift):
                echo " ";
                break;

            default:
                ?>
                    <form  action="php-SM-Request-Friend+Function.php" id="Button">
                        <a
                            type="button"
                            name="Chat"
                            id="Chat"
                            value="Chat">Chat</a>
                        <ipuut
                            type="submit"
                            name="SentRequest"
                            id="Request">Sent Request</ipuut>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Friend_ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Info_User_ID']?>">
                    </form> 
                <?php
                break;

        }

    } }else{    echo "You Don't Have Any Friends"; }


?>
```

Comment: Run please this func to check how much rows do you have in db https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysqli_num_rows-function/

Comment: It is because you have assigned your buttons in the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is duplicating the buttons  because you have assigned it in the `while` loop and as mentioned in the while loop it will keep duplicating the buttons on the bases of number of elements present in the array.So try changing your code arrangements as follows

```
<?php include"php-MAIN-Info.php"; 
include"php-MAIN-SignUp+DataBase.php"; $result1 =
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE user_one =
'".$User_ID."' OR user_two = '".$User_ID."'");

 1. List item

if ($result1) {     while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $day = $_SESSION['Info_User_ID'];       $longShift = true;
        switch (true) {
            case ($day == $row1['user_one']):
                echo " ";
                break;
            case ($day == $row1['user_two']):
                echo " ";
                break;
            case ($day == 'Friday' && !$longShift):
                echo " ";
                break;
            default:                     
               break;
        }
    } }else{    echo "You Don't Have Any Friends"; }

?>

<form  action="php-SM-Request-Friend+Function.php" id="Button">
                        <a
                            type="button"
                            name="Chat"
                            id="Chat"
                            value="Chat">Chat</a>
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            name="SentRequest"
                            id="Request">Sent Request</input>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Friend_ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Info_User_ID']?>">
                    </form>
```

And yes also make changes in the input tag in the form,you have assigned it as `ipuut`.